# How to collect/combine terms with two elements in Maple

Tags: maple

I want to collect terms with two elements in Maple equations:

```
A:=int(f(x)*(x+b*x+c),x);
```

All of the following fails:

```
collect(A,f(x)*x);
collect(expand(A), x);
collect(expand(A), x,simplify);
simplify(A);
simplify(expand(A));
```

[image]

What I want is :

```
(b + 1)*int(f(x)*x, x) + c*int(f(x), x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by collecting terms with two elements.

But your target can be obtained like this:

```
A := int(f(x)*(x+b*x+c),x):

collect(IntegrationTools:-Expand(A),int);

     (b+1)*int(f(x)*x,x)+c*int(f(x),x)
```